# Cocoa- how to make a TCP Socket with ARC?

Tags: cocoa, sockets, stream, tcpclient

Do you know some good tutorial that teaches how to make a simples TCP socket connection to a ip, and just send JSON to it?

I'm getting depressed, cause I can't find something easy to implement (I'm a fresh noob yet).

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well i just followed the raywenderlich tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

and maked a little adjustment to the initiation of the stream:

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunication {
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 1256, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = objc_unretainedObject(readStream);
    outputStream = objc_unretainedObject(writeStream);
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}
```

Comment: You may also be interested in CocoaAsyncSocket which does this all very well. https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/